# Python lxml cant navigate when using namespace

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a python script that is reading in an xml file using lxml.  However lxml is getting thrown off by the namespace.    Ie if delete `xmlns="http://theurl.com"` from my xml file before running the script it works fine and finds all the `elements.`  I am really struggling on how to modify the script to make it so I dont need to delete the name space reference from the xml file before parsing.

Sample Code

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse(r'myfile.xml')

Elements=[]
for elements in root.xpath('//element'):
      print(list(elements.keys()))
```

Sample File.

```
 <ServiceDefinition xmlns="http://theurl.com" " version="1.0.1.0">
      <schema>
         <seqtype="xyz">
            <element name="element 1"/>
            <element name="element 2"/>
         </seqtype>
       </schema>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: [See here](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) for more info on namespaces in lxml.

Comment: I was able to amend my code using the information in that solution